# Shell Script call a function with a variable?

Tags: function, shell, variables, call

Hi I'm creating a shell script.

and an example code looks like

```
#!/bin/bash

test_func(){
{
  echo "It works!"
}

funcion_name = "test_func"
```

I want to somehow be able to call test_func() using the variable "function_name"

I know that's possible in php using call_user_func($function_name) or by sying $function_name()

is this also possible in the shell scripting?

Huge appreciation for the help! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
test_func() {
    echo "It works!"
}

function_name="test_func"

eval ${function_name}
```

Answer (score 10):

You want the bash built-in `eval`.  From `man bash`:

`eval [arg ...]
              The args are read and concatenated together into a single command.  This command is then read and executed by the shell, and its exit status is returned as the value of eval.  If there are no
              args, or only null arguments, eval returns 0.`

You can also accomplish it with simple variable substitution, as in

```
#!/bin/bash

test_func() {
  echo "It works!"
}

function_name="test_func"

$function_name
```

Comment: trying one of your hints, it tries to execute the test_func as a shell command instead of calling the function :(

Comment: @Ben - not sure what you mean - both ways work for me.  When you define a function it essentially becomes a shell command.  If you give a more specific example of what doesn't work, it might help.

Comment: Very _javascvript-esque_!